# PHP Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, json

I'm using PHP to populate my DataTables select boxes.
If I add a new entry using the DataTables page (clicking in the 'Add' button), I have no problem with the accents (special characters), but if I do add new entries using the phpMyAdmin page (sql command), the fields that were added via the phpMyAdmin page that contains accents are not displayed(json_encode returns null for this fields).

Here's the line error:

```
aDataInitial = '<?php  echo json_encode($stack); ?>';'
```

I've tried to use utf8_encode, tried to declare the mysqli charset as UTF8, my MySQL charset is UTF8 by default.

Why does the entries that are added via the DataTable page are displayed fine while the entries added by phpMyAdmin are not?

Here's my HTML/PHP code:

```
<?php   
    $connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'mbrconsu_un394x',  'y1cz9,rd+hf6')) or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
    ((bool)mysqli_query( $connection, "USE mbrconsu_mmx")) or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));

    $aFieldType = array ('tema', 'vinculo', 'empresa', 'subcontratada', 'gerencia', 'areasolicitante', 'cc');
    $stack=array();

    foreach ($aFieldType as $type)
    {
        $sql="SELECT {$type} FROM treinamentos ORDER BY {$type} ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $stack[$type][] = array($row[$type],$row[$type]);
        }
    }
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            aDataInitial = '<?php  echo json_encode($stack); ?>';
        </script>
```

Comment: Set the connection to MySQL to utf8 (`SET NAMES utf8;`).

Comment: First thing after the `connect`.

Comment: Is this right? mysqli_connect('localhost',  'mbrconsu_un394x',  'y1cz9,rd+hf6')); mysqli_query(“SET NAMES 'utf8'”);

Comment: The quotes aren't strictly necessary, but it should work either way.

Comment: Because for some reason, you are using fancy quotes (`“`) instead of actual quotes that PHP understands (`"`)... What kind of editor are you using that thinks it's OK to use fancy quotes for this?

Comment: I'm getting this error  syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_query' (T_STRING), tried to insert semicolons, but then the error changes to unexpected ';'

Comment: Here's the line: ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'mbrconsu_un394x',  'y1cz9,rd+hf6') mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")) or die

Comment: I think you forgot the semi-comma (';') between hf6') and mysqli_query

Comment: Ah, I see the issue here. You did take me _very_ literal when I said first thing after the connect. Of course, I mean without destroying your connect syntax... So your `$GL.. mysqli_connect()... or ..;` and only _then_ the `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I did this: $connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'mbrconsu_un394x',  'y1cz9,rd+hf6')) or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
 mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: There's no more errors, but the special character fields still 'null'.